# Where to place the .register() method to set an initial/default value for UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swiftui, userdefaults

I am currently struggling to figure out where to correctly place the .register() method to set an initial/default value for UserDefaults (on every launch of the app).

Here is where I tried to initialize it in the "App" file that Xcode generated with the project:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {

    init() {
        //Sets default values for the user defaults that have not yet been set and should not return 0/false
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
                "selectedRoundLength": 1
            ]
        )
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't really seem to do the trick. Does anyone have input on this one?

Comment: In what way doesn’t it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This `init` is called before `UIApplication` has set up yet, so if you want to register defaults (which can be done from plist of big dictionary) it should be done via app delegate adapter.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

        // Register defaults here !!
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
                "selectedRoundLength": 1
                // ... other settings
            ]
        )

        return true
    }
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {

    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your minimum target is iOS 14, you can use `@AppStorage` to save your value in `UserDefaults` and start with an initial value. You don't particularly need to add this `@AppStorage` value in the `@main` to initialise it. You can just call it in any SwiftUI view or `Observable` class where you really need it. It will have this initial value if none has been saved.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {

  // This is UserDefaults starting in iOS 14.
  @AppStorage("selectedRoundLength") var selectedRoundLength = 1

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
  }
}
```